# The pipe command in Rstudio stopped working

Tags: r, rstudio, magrittr

Have anyone else experienced a problem when you use the keyboard shortcut for the pipe operator in RStudio? I mean the `ctrl + shift + M`. I do not know what happened but now if I type it it just doesn't write it in the script.
Help

Comment: Go to Tools...Modify Keyboard Shortcuts. Use the filter box to search for "Insert Pipe Operator". Do you have a shortcut set there? It would also be helpful to specify which version of RStudio you are running.

Comment: I've seen a couple of references online to a similar issue involving AMD Radeon graphics cards: [example](https://community.rstudio.com/t/keyboard-shortcuts-not-working/78477)